Changes in frontend not reflected in production without manually hard refresh
I using next js 12.3.4 problem is that
when I push new static front end related changes in production its not showing without hard refresh. to create similar situation on locale I test that
on one terminal I create new build by npm run build
on second terminal I start npm start
now If I made any html/css ui related change and on create new build for that (npm start is runing on one terminal ) after that build complete when I check changes in browser it not reflect
I have to use Hard refresh and after that this changes reflect in UI
anyone can share some solution  for this problem
i tried creating unique production build id in next config file as well I created one version.json file in public and in root I check if local storage version mismatch with version.json file than I do router.refresh and version update with each npm run build command
but I am getting last version in root file of project so this also not working
